# Set Tab Positions in Word with Powershell

Tags: powershell, docx

I am authoring a docx file with Powershell and am adding tabs using `t and this works fine.

My question is how do I edit the tab positions?

I have found a property of TabStops but it dose not appear to exist in the Selection object that I have got from a Word.Application object.

Thanks in advance,
Norman

Answer (score 1):

The `Selection` object does not have `TabStops`, what you want is `Word.Application.Selection.Paragraphs.TabStops` to manipulate the `TabStops`.

Or, if you have a range that you want to specifically modify `Range([ref]Char#,[ref]Char#).Paragraphs.TabStops` works too.

Comment: Thanks. Is Char# relative to the start of the document or is there a way to say "for the next paragraph I output"?

Comment: It's relative to the beginning of the document, but if I remember right there's a method to select everything until it finds a paragraph with different tabstops, so you should be able to modify sections at a time. You probably want to checkout the [Selection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection_members.aspx) reference page, specifically things like [SelectCurrentTabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.selectcurrenttabs.aspx)